# TypeError: storage must be a werkzeug.FileStorage

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug, file-storage

I am trying to save images in the filesystem in Flask app. It works fine. I can upload photos and retrieve them. But when i click on Submit without seleting any image it gives me an error:

> TypeError: storage must be a werkzeug.FileStorage.

Any help please!!

I have very little experience  so I am out of element here. The error comes from the flask_uploads.py:

> def save(self, storage, folder=None, name=None):
>           """
>           This saves a `werkzeug.FileStorage` into this upload set. If the
>           upload is not allowed, an `UploadNotAllowed` error will be raised.
>           Otherwise, the file will be saved and its name (including the folder)
>           will be returned.

```
    :param storage: The uploaded file to save.
    :param folder: The subfolder within the upload set to save to.
    :param name: The name to save the file as. If it ends with a dot, the
                 file's extension will be appended to the end. (If you
                 are using `name`, you can include the folder in the
                 `name` instead of explicitly using `folder`, i.e.
                 ``uset.save(file, name="someguy/photo_123.")``
    """
    if not isinstance(storage, FileStorage):
        raise TypeError("storage must be a werkzeug.FileStorage")
```

from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES

form = Add***()

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    image_url = photos.url(photos.save(form.image.data))  
    new_**** = ****(screenname= form.screenname.data, fullname = form.fullname.data, team = form.team.data, image=image_url)


db.session.add(new_****)
    db.session.commit()
    flash("Added Successfully")
    return redirect (url_for('****'))

return render_template("****.html", form=form)
```

I expected the html to return to the page if the image was not selected.